# PHP display pop-up success message box using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am try to display a pop-up success message box after a record is updated. Here is the codes I wrote in controller

```
           $status = $this->order_model->set_bookingByOrderID($id,$data);

           if($status ==1)
           {
            echo '<script>alert("You Have Successfully updated this Record!");</script>';
            redirect('orderManagement/index');
           }
           else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata("message","Record Not Updated!");
            redirect('orderManagement/index');
           }
```

but the script does not work. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: either redirect or show alert message but dont try to do both at once

Comment: Why not just use flashdata for both if you are wanting to redirect?

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and just need to put a refresh on redirect. Please try this code:

```
if($status == 1)
           {
               echo '<script>alert("You Have Successfully updated this Record!");</script>';
               redirect('orderManagement/index', 'refresh');
           }
           else{
               $this->session->set_flashdata("message","Record Not Updated!");
               redirect('orderManagement/index', 'refresh');
           }
```

I hope this will help you.